# How to replace a comma if followed by any digit?

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following line:

```
$str = "Very lovely, I mean very;Age 14,Angie;Price 12,99";
```

So I would like to replace a comma by a point that is ****followed** by** any **digit**.

The result should look like:

```
$str_updated = "Very lovely, I mean very;Age 14,Angie;Price 12.99";
```

The difference is **12,99** is now **12.99**

Any smart suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modified the first example from https://www.php.net/preg_replace

```
$string = 'Very lovely, I mean very;Age 14,Angie;Price 12,99';
$pattern = '/(\d+),(\d+)/i';
$replacement = '$1.$2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

The result can also be assigned to a variable, the `echo` here is just for the example.

I'm not sure how great the performance of this code is, so you might want to wait for someone to post a faster solution (if such exists).

Comment: This will not work with prices greater than 999,99 and formatted with thousands separators. For example a price of 1.234,56 would become 1.234.56, while in fact it should become 1,234.56 or 1'234.56 or 1 234.56 or ...

Comment: @lukas.j - To be honest that is the first time I'm seeing such a price format. My solution works for the provided example in the question, but I have no idea how to handle the case you mentioned, so someone else should provide a better answer and Jurgen should mark theirs as the accepted one.

Comment: Germany for example uses 1.234,56. It can become really complicated when taking into account all possible currencies. There are even currencies which group in hundreds instead of thousands.